# Couldn't find an answer before..struggling with css positioning

Tags: html, css, image, iframe

Trying to have an iframe appear within an image. Not working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/bKPKh/

HTML

```
<div id="comp_div">
<img src="Comp.png" id="comp">
<iframe width="700" height="526" src= 
"http://www.youtube.com/embed/1d7td7izg-8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't, images can't have child tags. Also, your markup is invalid anyway.

Comment: Okay- How is the markup invalid?

Comment: Well, if you wanted it contained inside the image, you'd wrap the frame in `<img>` tags, which you can't do.

Comment: Is it therefore not possible to position the iframe within the image in some capacity without it moving on browser re sizing? Maybe not within the image through the markup, but through CSS positioning?

Comment: How about setting position absolute in CSS?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, what does it mean to have an iframe "inside" an image? Do you mean overlay the frame over an image?

Comment: Correct. I apologize if my verbage was off. Within the JFiddle you can see a computer screen. The idea is to have the iframe appear within the  "monitor" area of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div#comp_div position:relative;

and position the iframe absolute over the image

something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/bKPKh/2/

```
<div class="monitor">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Et22afT.png" height="200" width="200"/>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="185" width="110"></iframe>
</div>

.monitor {
    position: relative;
}

.monitor iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 185px;
    height: 110px;
    top: 22px;
    left: 9px;
    border: 0;
}
```